# this program can't start because libeay32.dll is missing from your computer

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, dll, runtime-error

I don't need `libeay32.dll` in my project. I have already added `ssleay32.lib` in my application. This was working fine in visual studio 2010 version of my app. When I ported it in visual studio 2013 this error occurred. Where do I remove the settings so that my application doesn't search for `libeay32.dll`? My project built successfully. When I try to run the exe file or run the project than this shows up.

Comment: The openssl was built with dynamic linking option. That is why it was searching for the dll. After rebuilding it with statically linking option its fixed.

Answer (score 0):

It is library for SSL. You probably need to install [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/related/binaries.html) or just download it from some website and copy it to system folder.

Comment: This I know. But like I said I don't want this dll. I want to edit the settings so that the app won't search for it.

Comment: Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/et61xzb3.aspx), it is topic how to remove dependencies in project. It helped me last time, when I had similar problem.

Comment: I think this settings is related to project building. My project builds fine.