# Settings of Visual Studio to remove dependency on a dll file during runtime

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, dll

Everywhere people are suggesting how to let visual studio know when visual studio at run time doesn't find a dll. But I want to know where do I remove the option so that visual studio at run time doesn't try to find a dll file? I have a similar question about it yesterday with no answer in [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25377341/this-program-cant-start-because-libeay32-dll-is-missing-from-your-computer)

Comment: Uhh, if you stop calling functions from the DLL, it will stop looking. What's the real problem here?

Comment: It was a problem with the dynamically linked openssl library. Its fixed now. Thanks for replying. Wondering what could be the cause of down voting!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several options are available:

1. Remove the import library file from your project.  Go to the Visual Studio linker settings and remove the entry (`Properties -> Linker -> Input`).
2. If the library is specified by a `#pragma comment(lib:"xxxx")` (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/153901), then remove that line from your source file(s) and rebuild your application.
3. If you really want to use the library, but only if certain runtime conditions are met, then use `1.` or `2.` above, but change your source code to use `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress` to dynamically load the library and obtain the function pointers at runtime.

There is also a thing called `Delay Loaded DLL's`.  If this is what you're after, here is the link to the information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/151kt790.aspx

Comment: I don't have the `libeay32.dll` file as an entry in the `Properties -> Linker -> Input`. Also I don't have the lib in `pragma` directive anywhere in the code. I only have `ws2_32.lib` and `winmm.lib`, these two libraries in pragma directive. Also in `Code Generation -> Runtime Library` option /MTd is set. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: No, the `*.lib` file will be in the Linker settings, not the DLL name.  Somewhere you are specifying that the library is a dependency, as an application just doesn't pick up DLL's by random.  Also, you should use Dependency Walker on your application to see what your app is dependent on.  If you see the name in Dependency Walker (http://www.dependencywalker.com/), then you are indeed specifying the lib file in your settings.

Comment: Yes `ssleay32.lib` and `libeay32.lib` are in the linker settings. And I also have specified the path for them. But why it is searching for the dll file?

Comment: @Tahlil Because that's the way it works.  You specify an import library, and at runtime, those DLL's that the imports are tied to will be searched for.  Again, use Dependency Walker on the application you built.  Do you see the names of the DLL's you don't want to load show up as a dependency?  There is something called "delay loaded DLL", but not sure if this is what you want.

Comment: Yes it shows up under the module column. Also shows an error opening file.

Comment: Some errors in the dependency walker `Error: At least one required implicit or forwarded dependency was not found.
Warning: At least one delay-load dependency module was not found.
Warning: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in a delay-load dependent module.`

Comment: @Tahlil - So why are you including those lib files in your project if you don't want to use the DLL's that they are associated with?

Comment: I want to use these lib files because I need to use openssl. And I have been using them in visual studio 2010 without this missing dll problem. But when I needed to port it in VS2013 I got some error which indicated that I need to rebuild my openssl library because it was built in old compiler. So I rebuilt it and those two lib files were generated. And now the issue of having a dll file is occuring. But it worked fine without this dll before in VS2010!

Comment: Is it a issue with openssl building? Is the Openssl built with dynamically linking option? Do I have to rebuild it with statically linking option?

Comment: I got it. This was openssl building with dynamically linking option problem. Now I have built it again with statically linking and this error went away :D Thanks so much for the help.